# Samsung multiple app icons

Tags: samsung, onedrive

The OneDrive app on my Samsung A7(2017) has four icons on the home screen. What's happening and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You must have moved them to your homescreen from your app drawer.

To remove the extra ones, simply long press on one of them and drag it to the *remove* icon on the top of your screen. Do the same for the rest of the apps

Comment: No, I don't have a menu, all my icons are on the home screen, just like Apple or Huawei. I think it's because it updated and now there are four icons on the "desktop". This also happened to my YouTube as well and now I have 2 YouTube icons.